# Submit a form after finished Ajax request

Tags: jquery, forms

I want to submit a signup form. In the form onload I called one JavaScript function to validate all the fields.

Here I should call one ajax function to validate one field.

```
var checkExists = true;

checkExists = ajaxQuery(data);

if (checkExists) {

    alert('Already exists');

   return false;

}
```

`ajaxquery` is an ajax function which will return true or false based on the result.
My problem is that no matter what the AJAX result is, it will first execute the `if` condition and return false.

So my form always gets stuck even `checkExists` variable value is `false`. Please help

Comment: What does your ajaxQuery function look like? You should use a callback function from the ajax call so you will only execute the if statement when you get a response back.

Answer (score 3):

because ajax query is asychronous, you need to put your code in the **callback** method of ajaxQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(data){
     // your logic goes here.
     alert('Already exists');
     return false;
  }
});
```